# SQL query returns abnormally large count numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema roughly translates to the following:

```
reservation: reservation_id, inventory_id
inventory: inventory_id, car_id
car: car_id
feature: feature_id, name
car_feature: car_id, feature_id
```

The design is relatively simple. A few unnecessary columns are omitted, but the basic idea is that reservations are made for inventory items. Inventory items can be cars, which have car_ids. A car can have many features (and features can apply to several cars).

What I want to do is find the number of reservations made for each type of feature. Example: a table with one column being the feature "name", and another column being the number of reservations made for cars with that feature. For pedantic reasons, I do *not* want to use any nested queries.

Here is the query that I attempted:

```
select f.name, count(*) as reservation_count
from reservation r, inventory i, car c, car_feature cf, feature f
where r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id and i.car_id = cf.car_id and cf.feature_id = f.feature_id
group by f.name;
```

The query correctly returns each named feature in the following result tableset:

```
-name-    -reservation_count-
spokes     945000
wheels     931000
sunroof    104000
...        ...
```

However, it takes an abnormally large amount of time to compute (11 seconds for a dataset with a few thousand rows), and the reservation counts are way too high- there are only 16k rentals in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are joining along multiple independent dimensions, which is causing a problem with cartesian products.  The solution is to pre-aggregate the data along each dimension independently.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "pre-aggregate" the data? I thought I was already doing so with the `count` and `group by`.

Comment: if you're using mysql, type EXPLAIN before your sql statement and let us know the results.

Comment: The reason is you missed the join between inventory.car_id and car.car_id

Comment: Here's the explain result: https://gist.github.com/grahamcracker/e4332af9d92656f6c10e

Comment: @Gerrat Where would I put that join? I assume it would be an inner join?

Comment: try indexing the columns that you're joining. (regular index)  A describe table result would be helpful.

Comment: This is another good example why using the explicit `JOIN` operator is better than implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause - you can't accidentely create a cartesian product

Comment: You said: `Inventory items can be cars, which have car_ids.`, but you're not joining these anywhere.  An inner join would mean you're only interested in inventory items that are cars.  If that's what you want, then yes.

Comment: Hmmm...nevermind... upon a closer look, your car table seems to be completely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking "car c," out of your query. This will take out some redundant rows because you do not join to it. Having it included the way you do will just make n-car copies of each feature.

And for speed, try indexing the columns you join on. (see the DESCRIBE comment)

Comment: That worked! Is it because I never needed any data from the `car` model? Also, geoandri's answer worked too- what is the difference between them, since I didn't need any joins with our answer?

Comment: ya, in your query you don't need it because there's no joining to it (you can go from inventory to feature without using it). Having it will just make N copies of each feature where N is the number of rows in your car table.  glad it worked.

Comment: Which is better- using this method or joins? Or is my syntax just a shortcut for joins?

Comment: whatever way you can more easily read and/or understand. I prefer the way you wrote it, but opinions will vary.

Comment: you're welcome.  I would suggest running geoandri's query as well and if it works, be sure to up-vote it.  It may help somebody else who likes that style of query.

Answer (score 2):

I think the  following query will return the result you need

```
 Select feature.name, COUNT(reservation.reservation_id) as reservation_count
 from feature
 inner join car_feature on feature.feature_id=car_feature.feature_id
 inner join car  on car_feature.car_id=car.car_id
 inner join inventory on  car.car_id=inventory.car_id
 inner join reservation on inventory.inventory_id = reservation.inventory_id
 GROUP BY feature.name
```

Answer (score 2):

A big chunk of your problem is that you are using old-skool, pre-ANSI/ISO style joins. Which makes it hard to see what you're doing.

Lets take your original query and format it bit, so we can more easily see what's going on:

```
select f.name   ,
       count(*) as reservation_count
from reservation r  ,
     inventory   i  ,
     car         c  ,
     car_feature cf ,
     feature     f
where r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  and i.car_id       = cf.car_id
  and cf.feature_id  = f.feature_id
group by f.name
;
```

And now, let's translate that into ANSI join syntax:

```
select f.name   ,
       count(*) as reservation_count
from reservation r
join inventory   i  on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
join car         c  on ???
join car_feature cf on cf.car_id      = i.car_id
join feature     f  on f.feature_id   = cf.feature_id
group by f.name
```

Hmmm...That doesn't look quite right, does it? Somehow, the `car` table seems to have been omitted from the join criteria.

If we flesh things out in a likely way, using the schema you provided, we get something like this:

```
select f.name   ,
       count(*) as reservation_count
from reservation r
join inventory   i  on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
join car         c  on c.car_id       = i.care_id
join car_feature cf on cf.car_id      = c.car_id
join feature     f  on f.feature_id   = cf.feature_id
group by f.name
```

This will likely give you the results you want.

You might notice that's it's also a whole lot easier to read and understand.

As an added bonus, sorting out problems is a lot easier to. Change the the statement to `select count(*)`, comment out all the join clauses and the where clause (if any), thus

```
select --f.name   ,
       --count(*) as reservation_count
count(*)
from reservation r
--join inventory   i  on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
--join car         c  on c.car_id       = i.care_id
--join car_feature cf on cf.car_id      = c.car_id
--join feature     f  on f.feature_id   = cf.feature_id
--group by f.name
```

Running that should give you the raw number reservations.

Adding in the join to the inventory table

```
select --f.name   ,
       --count(*) as reservation_count
count(*)
from reservation r
join inventory   i  on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
--join car         c  on c.car_id       = i.care_id
--join car_feature cf on cf.car_id      = c.car_id
--join feature     f  on f.feature_id   = cf.feature_id
--group by f.name
```

should give you, I would imagine, the same reservation count. If the number is different from what you expect, there's a good change that your join criteria isn't correct or that you don't prperly understand the cardinality of the relationship involved.

Repeat until you've added all the joined tables back in. Then start uncommenting the `where` clause one bit at a time, verifying that your numbers are what you expect.

Once you're happy that your query is good, put the columns in the result list back and uncomment the `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extremely detailed and easy to understand answer! That makes so much more sense now. Wish I could upvote more than once!